# How recursively get all keys of nested object?

Tags: typescript, recursion

```
type NestedObject = {
 amount: number,
 error: string | null,
 data: {
  rows: [],
  messages: {
   goodNews: string | null,
   badNews: string | null
  }
 }
}

//trying recursively get all keys 
type AllKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = 
 T extends object ?
  T extends infer O ? 
   {keys: K | AllKeys<O, keyof O> : never
 : K

type Test = AllKeys<NestedObject, keyof NestedObject>
```

as a result I have:

```
type Test = { keys: 'amount' | 'error' | 'data' | ... }
```

but I need to get:

```
type Test = { keys: 'amount' | 'error' | 'data' | 'rows' | 'messages' | 'goodNews' | 'badNews'}
```

Comment: Both solutions are worked. Thanks very much. I have been trying to solve it without success pretty much time. It is only left to understand the solutions of TS masters ) My respect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
type RecursiveKeyof<T> = T extends object ? (
    T extends readonly any[] ? RecursiveKeyof<T[number]> : (
        keyof T | RecursiveKeyof<T[keyof T]>
    )
) : never
```

This recurses down into object types, giving you the keys of all the subproperties and sub-subproperties, etc.  It ignores primitives (so no `keyof string`), and special-cases arrays so that you only get keys of the *elements* of the array and not the array itself (which has keys like `number` and `"push"`, `"pop"`, etc).

Your `AllKeys` seems to want a `keys` property so we can write it like this:

```
type AllKeys<T> = { keys: RecursiveKeyof<T> }
```

Let's see if it works:

```
type Test = AllKeys<NestedObject>
// type Test = {keys: "amount" | "error" | "data" | "rows" | "messages" | "goodNews" | "badNews" }
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDyAjAVhAxsKAvFAN4CwAUFFVAIYC2A9gK4B2wAXFC03ehAE4AaCtSgD+Dfp0T8AliwDmUAD5cmAG3XDK1ZDWA1OZHaKoSA7vE4BtALqCoI01ToJ4NBQiNPnohQwZkOEtpYDlFFTVNbV9TdBogiBCoGXklVW5NH1MAX2y88gKKUEgoACVcJn54WQA3CABpCBAGADMAHgAVAD5CKE6xAA8kFmR4KAYsXHwAfigACmyBiGGIUfH+CASGFnUQWhYQOyg5ipwqmvqmlo7O625eAVtezkWTUwBrZrb+yLOLuqNb63axfG79Z7ZACUFChUE4LAg9X4FGK4GgAEFNNd4F1ekRiFAwVZypVqoDrm08VAiuQStBOgh8EQseoce04IgUBhsHhuhQAPQCqD0-pMvrEYmcABE9GYbGlkWl4kkitU0r0BjVUGlFng2ulrng7k8+qV-kCwTN6viiUsipyQA)

Comment: Looks like we figured out more or less the same solution, but yours has some good explanation too.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
type NestedObject = {
 a: number,
 b: {
  bb: string[],
  cc: string,
  dd: {
    foo: string
    bar: {
      baz: 'qqq'
    }
  }
 }
}

type AllKeys<O extends object, K = O[keyof O]> =
  keyof O
  | (
    K extends any[]
      ? never
      : K extends object
        ? AllKeys<K>
        : never
  )

type Test = AllKeys<NestedObject>
```

[Here's my playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDOwIBMDyAjAVhAxsKAvFAN4BQUAhgFxQB2ArgLboQBOANOejWVFOtyiJWAS1oBzANoBdTnxw4awseLlRkyHuT5QAZgHt9S4KIna+6Cqy06dlgF40A5AEc3T81AC+2n99I+pKCQUACCADbhANIQIPAAPKhQEAAeSLTI8FD6WLjA7FBRhFCokgDWsfq6JdIAfITaFSBVJdoAPlAAFJ5FqemZlLQgMp58APx0EABubKNQNL1pEBlZOdh4c+NhkTFx8VG1m-OTM6zaAJSkQeDQACoI+EQR0bEJcIgoGOvAh0A)