# Recursively get all keys using mapped type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types, recursive-type

I know this question has been asked before, and that there are working approaches, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129268/6576953), but I have a specific question about why a certain implementation using mapped types does not work:

When trying to recursively get all keys of a nested object, you need to handle the case of an array, so I wrote this type:

```
type KeysDeep<T> = T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]-?:
        | K
        | (T[K] extends (infer A)[] ? KeysDeep<A> : KeysDeep<T[K]>);
    }[keyof T]
  : never;
```

And this seems to work well, *except* if a property with an array type is optional, e.g.

```
type Foo = {
    foo: string;
}

type Bar = {
    bar: string;
    foos: Foo[];
}

type Baz = {
    baz: string;
    maybeFoos?: Foo[];
}

type Good = KeysDeep<Bar>; // "foos" | "bar" | "foo"
type Bad = KeyDeep<Baz>; // "foos" | "bar" | "foo" | ... a zillion more
```

I would have thought the `?-` operator would have adequately handled the optional property here. I've tried modifying this type in several ways but have been unable to make it work. Is there any way to fix this issue?

In the end, it's fine to use the solution I linked above, however it has poorer intellisense. e.g. the intellisense tooltip will list something like `"foo" | keyof Bar` instead of `"foos" | "bar" | "foo"`.

Anyway, this isn't a huge deal, but I'm just curious if there's a fix and as to why this doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcAiEJgEICcD2BrCAdgDwAqAfFALxQlQQAewhAJglNgEYBWEAxsACgoUAPxQA3kOHSA2jCgBLAlHwhsAMxoBdALQiAXFOnSAPrCPGoZuIhRoseQqTlayAbgsBfGao3ap%20lAEEABuEJgeAqCQsPDIqGAAMhAICA74xORUNHSMLGycPPxSYpKWUHKKyr6aJLoGFsbWjaZQABQkLrlMBKxQmBAAhszYBAA2IO1K6uFQAIIAlDJaorG2Ccmp6U5zFIE28WibaTgZzjCuCx7G3jX%20woHBYRECr9HQAGLY2Nll0urfQIIYCYJQAcw8nje4Gg6EGmF%20Fg48KBIPB13%203wQgS%202GWkOhMThAC9EcZkcTUaCCBCLABbQYgDgQXEIAxQXH4gRQqIwqBw5jZA52DCnJxwzDuXkxADi30F1GFGxSJ0cxAlUve-OGczBgyUQriIuO23Vg2JUul0CVaAA6thMLhwaQKNRaAwen1CnxgKs2hZ3XlemwBsNRhMpgQZgiAKpLFZiG1ge2O50xvbtFrCO60axGhIpp005w51wWBYCBZQR6hcKE2EpX2K-N2h1FsFEEnuIA) link with a full example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake happens in this line:

```
(T[K] extends (infer A)[] ? KeysDeep<A> : KeysDeep<T[K]>)
```

If `foos` is just `Foo[]`, this check works like expected. But when `foos` is optional, the type of `foos` is `undefined | Foo[]` which also will be the type of `T[K]`. The `-?` operator does not exclude `undefined` from `T[K]`. It will only remove `undefined` and `?` from the resulting mapped type which we only use for indexing.

The union of `undefined | Foo[]` does not extend `(infer A)[]`, only `Foo[]` does. That's why `T[K]` will also be passed to the `KeysDeep` in the false branch. You will see this massive union as a result which will happen when any array type is passed to the `KeysDeep` type because using a mapped type on an array (and indexing it with its keys) will also return any method properties of `Array`. You can see this happening [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEEBOiCG4DS1wGdYF5YBvWAbXVgEsA7WAaywHsAzEgXVYC5ZyBfE%208MzatgAelGxJAPQD8QA).

One solution would be to use `Exclude` to exclude `undefined` from `T[K]`.

```
(Exclude<T[K], undefined> extends (infer A)[] ? KeysDeep<A> : KeysDeep<T[K]>)
```

Or you could copy `T[K]` into a new type to distribute it.

```
(T[K] extends infer U 
  ? U extends (infer A)[] 
    ? KeysDeep<A> 
    : KeysDeep<T[K]> 
  : never
);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcAiEJgDwBUB8UC8UmUEAHsBAHYAmCUA9gEYBWEAxsAFBRQD8UA3l27CA2jCgBLClADW8OgDNCAXQC0PAFxDhwgD6xtOqPoAUmMcuJlKNSRQUQATlACqUQ0eF83pctVomUg7OAIIAlCKWHp5esPDIqBghuNExUBpxiChoWBYpaToZFBAAbk6pwmEA3IYAviJyIIoqQkWlTjUcHKCQmQloAExYuAREvja0jCzsQnyCnmJ2svJKmGqaFfowm1AmAKIkrAA2AK5UELkwygA0UCfUEApSEFS44-67QU5Q4ZG8fdkwENkukAYkhuYrthqnUGisWtw2mVHJ1uuBoAAxOh0fACQwKbEZBDARxSADmNVqXR60AAQgBDZwEebCBiMokk8k1HQEugIDJYuiRSnU9FQBkAL1xLO4bIlHNJFAphgAtvSQAwIIKEJooILhRwqWjegBxbFUXFwLLg9AMxzYKpQAD0TqgACJeQg3cZ3WzHN79B7sW7jXT6RaCFb+kDbfSJQ7na6g3yA77Gank6mAHQ5qD0qASiRHI4SOjSFV0RwQIA)

Comment: Awesome, thanks - this was really helpful. I figured `undefined | Foo[]` was the problem and tried to handle it a few different ways, but not with `Exclude`, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Thought I don't really understand how the second suggestion works... isn't `U` just the same as `T[K]` and wouldn't it have the same problem? i.e. `infer A` of `U` would only be `Foo[]` not undefined and undefined would stull get passed to `KeysDeep<T[K]>`? Or no, because if U is not an array type its just being discarded with the last `never`? A bit confusing... wouldn't every `T[K]` satisfy `infer U`?

Comment: copying `T[K]` into `infer U` will turn it into a *naked type*. In a conditional this type will be distributed. See the docs about [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). This will make the conditional handle all elements of the union separately.

Comment: This was also one of the things I since I had the hunch that when `T[K]` was `undefined` it was not satisfying `extends (infer A)[]`, why does this not work? `(T[K] extends undefined ? never : T[K] extends (infer A)[] ? KeysDeep<A> : KeysDeep<T[K]>)`

Comment: if `T[K]` is a union, it will also not satisfy `T[K] extends undefined`. Only `undefined ` extends `undefined` but not a union.